# How to show datepicker on focus of datefield

Tags: datepicker, extjs6.2

This should be quite simple but, in ExtJs 6.2, I can't figure out how to make the datepicker (calendar) open by itself when the datefield focus event fires. You would think there would be a method for that on the field itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
listeners:{
    focusenter: function(myfield,o,opt){
                       myfield.expand();           
                }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `focusenter` event will fire when focus enters in this Component's hierarchy. Try `focus` event instead

```
listeners:{
focus: function(thisObj, event, eOpts) {
      thisObj.expand();           
  }
}
```

Comment: Worked like a champ! Thanks so much!